# A Registration free activation COM dll built with VS2008 does not work in exe built with VS2013

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2008, com

I am a newbie to COM, I have implemented a sample COM registration-free activation Server.dll to be loaded by Client.exe.

I have successfully tested loading server.dll built with VS2012, VS2010 to be loaded by Client.exe built with VS2013 and it works fine.

But, actually need to use the Server.dll built with VS2008 in the Client.exe built with VS2013. Currently getting ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND error on CoGetClassObject() call. I am using ATL libs compatible with VS2008.

My question is,
Is it possible to load a COM based Server.dll built with VS2008 to load and work with Client.exe built using VS2013? Are there any extra steps to be done to get it working.

I am using Manifest.xml file to get around the need for Registration.

Comment: Getting ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND would be remarkable, it is a winapi error code and not an HRESULT (i.e. 0x8007007e).  It is otherwise a simple file-not-found error, not necessarily applying to the COM server itself.  Forgetting to deploy the CRT (like msvcr120.dll) is a traditional mistake.  An executable built with VS2008 uses a different CRT (msvcr90.dll), installed in the winsxs cache and very often available by accident.  Use loader snaps or Process Monitor to diagnose.

Comment: @HansPassant, I tried copying CRT libs (msvcr90.dll) for different x86 configs from WinSXS path and also from Visual Studio 2008 redistributables path they kept giving me the error although it complained about not using the correct CRTs from WinSXS folder. I then reverted to use the default CRTs it was using and error went away. I then tried debugging using Process Monitor, it was able to successfully find the "Server.dll". However during debug in Visual Studio, it loaded the Server.dll and immediately unloaded possibly it could not find or initialise something correctly?